# Images blurry on woo commerce detail page

Tags: woocommerce

Could someone please take a look at my page and let me know what I can do to fix the quality of the images on my woocommerce product detail page? If you look, the catalog images are fine, but when you click on an image and go to the detail page, the image is very large and blurry. I tried adjusting the Woocommerce image settings in addition to regenerating thumbnails through the plugin, but I haven't gotten the issue fixed.

Here is my site: monpetitfour.com/menu

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your theme is using the image thumbnail version in single product page template,

if you check the source code, you'll see it,

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://monpetitfour.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/brownies-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="brownies" title="brownies">
```

its should be the original image url -> http://monpetitfour.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/brownies.jpg

check **/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php**, your theme probably modify that file, and it should be on **your-theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php**

now look for that value of **$image** variable,

it usually start with `image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'thumbnail', blah blah blah`

make sure this line `apply_filters( 'thumbnail'` is something like `apply_filters( 'full'`

if its not and uses something like custom thumbnail size, then change to it `'full'`

Comment: When I checked that file, it has apply_filters ('single_product_large_thumbnail_size'.....I changed it to full, and also tried single_product_full_size....neither made a difference. I also just checked my wordpress media settings, and changed the thumbnail size from 150x150 to 800x800 to see if it would help, that didn't either.

Comment: based on the HTML source I posted above, it uses the `shop_single` 

Go to WOOCOMMERCE >> SYSTEM STATUS >> TOOLS >> then check "Template Debug Mode"

then see if it still uses the 150x150 size, it so, then the problem is your configuration, if its no longer uses 150x150, your theme overrides it

Comment: Just did as you advised, and the problem is still there even with the template debug mode checked. What do you mean its a configuration problem?

Comment: did you make sure the image size under Settings > Products > Single Product Image is not 150x150? 

turn off debug and try adding this in your functions.php
`apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', array(800, 800) );`

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. Not sure what happened, but all of a sudden the images are no longer blurry. Weird